# custom template tag library is not getting loaded when placed in a directory with undescore in name

Tags: python, django, django-templates, tags

I created a custom tag library file inside a directory name `template_tags`. I was not getting loaded and was throwing error -

```
'custom_template_tags' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_static
admin_urls
cache
future
i18n
l10n
log
static
staticfiles
tz
```

I have `__init__.py` in folder. I followed all tricks from SO but none worked until I renamed my directory to `templatetags`. I also tried moving template library outside the folder in app's directory but this also didn't worked.

So I have these questions here
1. Why tag library was not loaded without a directory?
2. When I placed tag library inside directory, why it needed name of directory without underscore in it. Is it done knowingly in django?

Comment: By default Django looks in `app/templatetags` for templatetag libraries. The name of the file will be the name of the library, for example `app/templatetags/my_tags.py` can be used like `{% load my_tags %}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout

> The app should contain a templatetags directory, at the same level as models.py, views.py, etc. If this doesn’t already exist, create it - don’t forget the `__init__.py` file to ensure the directory is treated as a Python package.